# MVC Route attribute not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Controller where I defined this `Route` attribute to retrieve an optional attribute from URL

```
[Route("Base/SingleOffer/{idOffer?}")]
public ActionResult SingleOffer(int? idOffer) {
    ...
    return View();
}
```

The `View` is rendered correctly when I use the following URL:

> /Base/SingleOffer
>
> /Base/SingleOffer?idOffer=5

But I get an error when using this URL

> /Base/SingleOffer/5

Specifically the error is

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it worked for me was to rename the optional parameter in `RoutConfig.cs` to what is on attribute, so in your case the URL would be : `url: "{controller}/{action}/{idOffer}"`

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "base",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{idOffer}",
               defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

***Or:***

Add  `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` to your `RouteConfig.cs` and you can use attribute routing and all paths would work (make sure there are no `routes.MapRoute();` as you want to use Attribute routing! ) e.g.

```
Base/SingleOffer            //idOffer would null
Base/SingleOffer?idOffer=5  //idOffer would be 5
Base/SingleOffer/5          //idOffer would be 5
```

Comment: this way it works but I prefer to use the `Route` attribute on a single `ActionView`

Comment: thank you, it works now! I've always used it in WebApi2 controllers, and I see now in the WebApiConfig.cs there is `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`, I guess this is the equivalent to enable `Route` attributes  in MVC